# Video.js Build on Windows Hangs on Minify Task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler, video.js

I'm trying to follow the [contributing instructions](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) for Video.js, and when I attempt to build the project grunt hangs on the minify step. Here's the output:

```
Running "minify" task

Running "minify:source" (minify) task
Verifying property minify.source exists in config...OK
Files: build/files/combined.video.js, build/compiler/goog.base.js, src/js/exports.js -> build/files/minified.video.js
Writing build/files/minified.video.js...OK
```

I get no error or message; it just hangs there for minutes. A file called minified.video.js is created in build/files, but it's empty. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong?

**Update:** I've tried it on <del>2</del> 3 computers now with the exact same results. Two of the computers are Windows 7 x64 and one is Windows 8 x64. My gut feeling is that closure is choking on the really long command that the build file sends to it, but I'm having a hard time debugging that.

**Update 2:** I modified the `Gruntfile.js` to make it output the full command it uses to call Closure, and then I tried running that directly. I got the following result: `0 error(s), 576 warning(s), 82.5% typed`. I would think that many warnings points to an issue, but I don't know what it could be. The full output from closure can be found here: http://pastebin.com/GZuFxiqh.

**Update 3:** I setup a virtual machine running Ubuntu and the build worked flawlessly. So, this is somehow Windows related, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never figured out why the build was failing for me. However, as of video.js version 4.4.2, I am able to build the project without problems. Maybe it was a configuration problem on my end, or maybe some bugs got fixed on their end, but this issue is now resolved.